# Use CommandButton Collection to update the font on command buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use vba to change the font on all of the ActiveX command buttons on several worksheets.  I know the font can be updated using vba because this code will do it for a single button

```
Private Sub CommandButton49_Click()
CommandButton49.Font = "Arial Rounded MT Bold"
End Sub
```

I have seen on this site a method for getting the collection

```
Dim MyShapes As OLEObjects
Dim btn As OLEObject
Dim cbtn As CommandButton

'OLE Programmatic Identifiers for Commandbuttons = Forms.CommandButton.1
Set MyShapes = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
For Each btn In MyShapes
   If btn.progID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
      btn.Object.Font = "Arial"
   End If
Next
```

but this code gives an run-time error 438 - Object does not support this property or method, which is strange because I can use this method to display the font - i.e. msgbox btn.Object.Font will display the current font.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should `Forms.CommandButton.1` be `Forms.CommandButton1`?

Comment: You're missing the `Name` property: `btn.Object.Font.Name = "Arial"`

Comment: Thanks Rory - now that makes me feel a little silly, but you are absolutely right - adding the .Name solves my problem.